# How to list files which I have committed today in SVN?

Tags: svn

I want to check what files I have committed today

I have tried
`svn log | grep 'name' | grep '2013-04-01'`

but it cut my comment and the files I committed

thanks for all answers

I search for something like `svn log -commited_by me`

finally I do

```
svn log -v `svn log -q -r {2013-04-01}:{2013-04-02} | grep myname | cut -d"|" -f1 | sed 's/r/\-r/g'`
```

I feel looong :^(

Comment: `svn log` maybe?  What is the task?

Comment: What have you tried? This is trivial with `svn log` but on SO, you are expected to show that you've at least attempted to solve the problem yourself

Answer (score 6):

You can specify a date to `svn log` and this will give you the most recent revision on that date.  You can also used dates in ranges so, for example, you might use:

```
svn log -r {2013-03-26}:{"2013-03-26 23:59"}
```

You should note that revisions *"the most recent revision on that date"* so the first revision is on the previous day.  (There's a note on this in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) entitled *"Is Subversion a Day Early?"*)  As such, the above example could just as easily be written as:

```
svn log -r {2013-03-26}:{2013-03-27}
```

Now you mention "today" in your original question, so you could build a command that puts in the dates automatically.  Now the `date` command can get you today's date with:

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

and tomorrow's date with

```
date -v+1d "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

so you can combine these approaches:

```
svn log -r {`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`}:{`date -v+1d "+%Y-%m-%d"`}
```

Comment: 1. END instead of (calculated) tomorrow can be just HEAD 2. First revision in log will be **always** outdated (I haven't *good* solution for this problem)

Comment: Agreed re HEAD but only the case where we're talking about "today".  I presented the functions in full using date should someone wish to modify it based on some other (non-today) date.

Comment: Re the first revision, it is my understanding that if I committed at 00:00 on a given day then the first revision would not be outdated.  Clearly an extreme case, but my reasoning behind "almost certainly" as a phrasing.

Comment: > "if I committed at 00:00 on a given day then the first revision would not be outdated" - no, will be, because "most recent **prior to** specified date", check it for revision with known date-time. For `>svn log -r {"2013-01-19 11:36:59"}` (exact time-stamp of revision) I get *previous*: you must use date at least one second later, than revision in order to get it

Comment: Yep, that does indeed appear to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

1. You **must to read** [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html), at least [Revision Specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) (don't miss "Is Subversion a Day Early?" section and **understand** it) topic and `svn help log`
2. You **must to learn** to answer on questions from comments for you

After it (with the help of some lines of code in order to get revision-range if you want to exclude very first revision from "easy try" attempt) you can get needed result.

It can be:

- `svn log -q -v -r BEGIN:END`
- `svn diff --summarize -r BEGIN:END`

(diff doesn't contain "noise", only a/ filelist without duplicates b/ status indicator of every affected file)

Answer (score 0):

@borrible's answer covers date ranges and @Lazy Badger's answer covers file listings, so I'll cover remaining part of the question -- limiting results to you.

You can use the `--search` option to filter by:

> the author, date, log message text (unless --quiet is used), or, if the --verbose option is also provided, a changed path.

Assuming your svn username is "Jing", we can put all the answers together to get:

```
svn log --quiet --verbose --revision {`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`}:{`date -v+1d "+%Y-%m-%d"`} --search Jing path/to/repo/root
```

Where `--quiet` is suppressing the commit message and `--verbose` is making filepaths appear. You must include the path to the root of your repo (on disk or URL) to include all changes and not just in the current folder.

You'll get results that look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r468951 | Jing | 2021-06-23 13:16:03 -0700 (Wed, 23 Jun 2021)
Changed paths:
   M /project/filter.py
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r468952 | Jing | 2021-06-23 13:19:34 -0700 (Wed, 23 Jun 2021)
Changed paths:
   M /project/filter.py
   M /project/results.py
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To see a list of unique filepaths, add `| grep "^ " | sort -u` to the command.

*Unfortunately* svn's filtering is limited so if your **username also appears in filepaths**, you'll have to use something like [pysvn](https://pypi.org/project/svn/) to filter the results.

Also, be aware that if you use a local path, you'll **only include results that you've sync**. If you want results that you don't yet have locally, you need to pass the url.